# Winforms WebBrowser embed Youtube video

Tags: c#, winforms, youtube, embed, webbrowser-control

So far I've been able to embed and show a Youtube video inside my winforms just fine..but I have a list of videos and I would like to be able to change the current URL to a new one, but for some reason it does not work..

```
WebBrowser wbYoutube = new WebBrowser();
wbYoutube.Url = new Uri("http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + datagridview1[0, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString() + "?autoplay=1");
panel1.Controls.Add(wbYoutube);
```

Now that works fine the first time, but when I click on the next video in my list, it doesn't refresh that WebBrowser nor panel.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are adding a new webbrowser each time. possibly, the newly added webbrowser is on the panel where you can not see it.

you should not add a new one each time.

do something like this, remove existing webbrowser first, assume there is no other browser in that panel1:

```
    foreach (Control c in panel1.Controls)
{
    if (c is WebBrowser)
    {
        panel1.Controls.Remove(c);
    }
}

WebBrowser wbYoutube = new WebBrowser();
wbYoutube.Url = new Uri("http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + datagridview1[0, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString() + "?autoplay=1");
panel1.Controls.Add(wbYoutube);
```

Comment: totally right, thank you so much! I started to wonder after I hit pause on the current video and could hear the other playing lol..